# Excel - How to solve this:(closed temporarily)

Tags: excel

I have a formula like this:
new x = 2x+a (the formula I use is more complex)
this goes on and on and I need to know how many times the formula should be repeated to get a specific result.
The starting value of x and a is defined by the user in a cell.

```
For a finite number, I attempted to do like this:
a=  1           
x=  9   0       
=[2*cell reference to upper cell+cell reference to 1 (freezed)] 1       10
Drag down... 2
...          3 etc.
Result = 10
=vlookup(cellreferenceto10,table,TRUE)
```

The problem is I am not getting the result for vlookup properly
and I need an infinite number (not just 10 or 1000)

(need at leas 10 rep to post images :( )

https://i.stack.imgur.com/amAU5.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSYt7.png

Comment: Math fact: you can't get an infinite number, because there is no such thing. Have you tried macros?

Comment: So it it not possible to get how many times I should do the formula to get the required result by using excel. the number could be fairly large. How is macros done to do this stuff?

Comment: Just found that it is called circular reference

Comment: I still do not clearly understand what you are attempting here. can you paste some formulas from an excel into your question?

Comment: Links to image added. I need to do till infinity, if not possible to a large number, as big as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computers can not count to infinity.

Excel is not the correct tool for you.

If you can state your problem in math terms you may be able to reduce its complexity to the point where you can display the results in Excel.

If you have trouble solving math run some experiments on http://www.wolframalpha.com/. Maybe you can simplify your solution there.

Your code may be very slow so turning of the output at the start of a vba function is usually a good idea. (and turning output on again at the end of course.)

You can also not use Excel Cells to build a recursive function, for that you need vba, or a completely other tool than excel.

---

EDIT:

It looks like you are trying to do financial math. If so pick one of [these](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Financial-functions-reference-5157fee4-8a47-46c2-ba00-467b31d721eb?CorrelationId=d8494c15-5a6e-4bb9-a6f9-b9539e19003e&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US) functions.

About your original question:

- X(0) = a
- X(1) = k * X(0) + a = (k+1) a
- X(2) = k * X(2) + a = (k² + k + 1 ) a
- X(3) = k * X(3) + a = (k³ + k² + k + 1 ) a

Your number just explodes, but i think the only thing that is broken is your lookup. I will try to simulate this and edit again.

---

EDIT:
Taken from the comment below:
 X(n+1) = (X(n) - 1)² / (4 X(n) ( X(n)² + a X(n) + 1 ) )

I do not want to get into the math behind this and i am not sure what this would model. Mathadvise could be found on another [exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/). It may be wise to ask if there is some way of reducing this so you get rid of the recursion.

However when modeling this you would have to ensure that the divisor never is 0. To do that you need to avoid certain areas of a and X(n) combinations. This is where [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%20%3D%204x%20%28x%5E2%20%2B%20a*x%20%2B%201%29) comes in handy again.

---

EDIT:
Since there are starting conditions where errors occur i would split the division and carry the error. Here is an example of how i would implement this:

[image: DemoExcelImplementation]

Comment: I tried wolframalpha and got computational time exceeded or something.

Comment: Can you give an example for stating it in math terms? for like 2x+a?

Comment: If you want to build the sum of something you would state it like the sum of X_i from i=0 to i=100. You want to write all as a one liner: MyExpectesResult = SUM_{i=0}1{10}(X). The advantage there is that you have solved for the thing you want to know. If you can write it in fragments but you can not solve it try to write the best fragments you can. If you can not create fragments write down a list of inputs and what you expect the outputs to be.

Comment: The formula is x=(x²-1)²/(4*x*(x²+a*x+1))  I am trying to reduce its complexity, but till now I have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Ah, ok. I will take a closer look at that formula.

Comment: You completely confused me just now. What is this a model of?

Comment: I did the same way you got (k+1)a, (k² + k + 1 ) a, etc. Since it was linear, it seemed small. If you try to do the same for that one you will get this. :) (and I did just first 3)

Comment: what is X(0) and what is a? Without X(0) the recursion would not end.

Comment: x(0)=9 and a can be any constant defined by the user. (check the pics i added to get an idea)      (accidentally deleted one of my comment, sry)

Comment: I just found an issue with the problem for which I asked this question. Please allow me some time to address it. Thank oyu for your time. Please consider this closed for some time. ty